# How to Create a Property in a Custom Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

The idea is to be able to set the f1-f4 keys to be settable at design time. Like the accept and canel buttons are in a normal form.

```
me.AcceptButton = Button1
```

I want to be able to have the same functionality as this property. as in accept button you press enter and it executes. I would like to be able to assign the F1-F4 keys to buttons.

```
me.F1Button = ButtonCalc
me.F2Button = ButtonClr
etc.
```

I have looked quite a bit into creating custom controls and have build a few but seem to have found no documentation on how to something similar. I am looking for any books, articles or guides about this.

Comment: Why not just use hotkeys?

Comment: Well this form is going to be used across probably 2 dozen programs so having that functionality would be nice.

Comment: Is this a form or a control?

Comment: This is a custom form that will have additional properties like the accept and cancel button but for the F1-F4 keys.

Comment: Okay, then within that form look for the "key down" event. Within that event have a select case for F4, F5, then call or raise an event that contains the stuff you wan to do

Comment: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/assign-keyboard-keys-vbnet-29287.html

Comment: Yeah i have that already and its not something i am happy with so i was looking for a better solution.

Comment: Well, you can always assign it to a menuitem if you have a menu with their shortcuts. You can also add one and then make it not visible, so the user doesn't see or know it's there.

Comment: But, the key down is a commonly used solution.

Comment: I was more looking for this because it was a good solution to the issue as well as good learning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inherit the form as your base class to get the designer to serialize the property, but this would be a simple example:

```vb
Public Property F1Button As Button

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, _
                                           keyData As Keys) As Boolean
  If keyData = Keys.F1 AndAlso F1Button IsNot Nothing Then
    F1Button.PerformClick()
    Return True
  End If
  Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up `KeyDown` event handlers for the form and all the buttons. You need to do this because the form may not have focus when the key is pressed.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    AddHandler CancelButton.KeyDown, AddressOf Form1_KeyDown
    AddHandler OKButton.KeyDown, AddressOf Form1_KeyDown
    AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf Form1_KeyDown
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.F1
            ' custom action
        Case Keys.F2
            ' custom action
        Case Keys.F3
            ' custom action
        Case Keys.F4
            ' custom action
    End Select
End Sub
```